# How to create a rule from within another rule in Bazel

Tags: bazel

## Situation

I have two Skylark extension rules: `blah_library` and `blah_binary`. All of a `blah_library`'s transitive dependencies are propagated by returning a `provider(transitive_deps=...)`, and are handled appropriately by any ultimate dependent `blah_binary` target.

## What I want to do

I want each `blah_library` to also create a `filegroup` with all the transitive dependencies mentioned above, so that I can access them separately. E.g., I'd like to be able to pass them in as data dependencies to a `cc_binary`. In other words:

```
# Somehow have this automatically create a target named `foo__trans_deps`?
blah_library(
    name = "foo",
    srcs = [...],
    deps = [...],
)

cc_binary(
    ...,
    data = [":foo__trans_deps"],
)
```

How should I do this? Any help would be appreciated!

## What I've tried

#### Make a macro

I tried making a macro like so:

```
_real_blah_library = rule(...)

def blah_library(name, *args, **kwargs):
    native.filegroup(
        name = name + "__trans_deps",
        srcs = ???,
    )
    _real_blah_library(name=name, *args, **kwargs)
```

But I'm not sure how to access the `provider` provided by `_real_blah_library` from within the macro, so I don't know how to populate the `filegroup`'s `srcs` field...

#### Modify the `blah_library` rule's implementation

Right now I have something like:

```
_blah_provider = provider(fields=['transitive_deps'])

def _blah_library_impl(ctx):
    ...

    trans_deps = []
    for dep in ctx.attr.deps:
        trans_deps += dep[_blah_provider].trans_deps

    return _blah_provider(trans_deps=trans_deps)

blah_library = rule(impl=_blah_library_impl, ...)
```

I tried adding the following to `_blah_library_impl`, but it didn't work because apparently `native.filegroup` can't be called within a rule's implementation ("`filegroup() cannot be called during the analysis phase`"):

```
def _blah_library_impl(ctx):
    ...

    trans_deps = []
    for dep in ctx.attr.deps:
        trans_deps += dep[_blah_provider].trans_deps

    native.filegroup(
        name = ctx.attr.name + "__trans_deps",
        srcs = trans_deps,
    )

    return _blah_provider(trans_deps=trans_deps)
```

Comment: Thanks for an excellent, clearly phrased question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up making my own special `filegroup`-like rule, as discussed in the comments under @Laszlo's answer. Here's the raw code in case it's a useful starting point for anyone:

```
def _whl_deps_filegroup_impl(ctx):
    input_wheels = ctx.attr.src[_PyZProvider].transitive_wheels
    output_wheels = []
    for wheel in input_wheels:
        file_name = wheel.basename
        output_wheel = ctx.actions.declare_file(file_name)
        # TODO(josh): Use symlinks instead of copying. Couldn't figure out how
        # to do this due to issues with constructing absolute paths...
        ctx.actions.run(
            outputs=[output_wheel],
            inputs=[wheel],
            arguments=[wheel.path, output_wheel.path],
            executable="cp",
            mnemonic="CopyWheel")
        output_wheels.append(output_wheel)

    return [DefaultInfo(files=depset(output_wheels))]

whl_deps_filegroup = rule(
    _whl_deps_filegroup_impl,
    attrs = {
        "src": attr.label(),
    },
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily create a filegroup like that, but you can still achieve what you want.

If you want to use the rule in `genrule.srcs`, `filegroup.srcs`, `cc_binary.data`, etc., then return a [`DefaultInfo`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/skylark/lib/globals.html#DefaultInfo) provider (along with `_blah_provider`) and set the `files` field to the transitive closure of files.

You can refine the solution if you want a different set of files when the rule is in a `data` attribute vs. when in any other (e.g. `srcs`): just also set the runfiles-related members in `DefaultInfo`. (Frankly I don't know the difference between them, I'd just set all runfiles-fields to the same value.)

Comment: Thanks for the info Laszlo! Much appreciated! Hmm, I'll take a look at whether what you're suggesting would work for my use case... The potential issue is that the transitive deps I'm talking about are sort of "auxiliary" files, so not sure they should be the default outputs... I guess I can always just make a custom `filegroup`-type target that handles `blah_library`s specially...

Comment: Yes, a custom filegroup-like rule as you describe would work well too.