# Bazel using cc_binary with custom providers

Tags: c++, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-cpp, starlark

So I discovered Bazel recently and wanted to compile my projects with it (that are using Premake right now).

I want to create a provider for each project that will contain all information about it. Like it defines, dependencies, includes directories, ..., and if it's a binary or a library. To simplify my example I have reduced it to just a little info.

```py
SolutionProjectInfo = provider("", fields = {
    'name': "",
    'project_type': "",
    'srcs': "",
    'defines': "",
    'include_dirs': ""
})
```

What I would like to do is to have a rule that will produce a `SolutionProjectInfo` and make a call to `cc_binary`.

```py
solution_project = rule(
    implementation = _impl_solution_project,
    attrs = {
        'project_type': attr.string(default = ProjectType.ConsoleApp),
        'srcs': attr.label_list(default = [], allow_files = True),
        'defines': attr.string_list(default = []),
        'include_dirs': attr.string_list(default = [])
    },
    provides = [SolutionProjectInfo]
)
```

Right now the implementation of `_impl_solution_project` is meaningless, cause I can't call `cc_binary` in a rule.

```py
def _impl_solution_project(ctx):
    return [SolutionProjectInfo(
        name = ctx.label.name,
        project_type = ctx.attr.project_type,
        defines = ctx.attr.defines,
        include_dirs = ctx.attr.include_dirs,
        srcs = ctx.attr.srcs
    )]
```

With that I could have just a BUILD file, in which I make a call to this rule `solution_project`.
But I have a big problem, I can't make a call to `cc_binary` in a rule, aka in `_impl_solution_project` the implementation of my rule `solution_project` (native.cc_binary can't be called within a rule's implementation).
It seems intended:
[How to create a rule from within another rule in Bazel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49885381/how-to-create-a-rule-from-within-another-rule-in-bazel)

And if I don't make my call to `cc_binary` in the function `_impl_solution_project`, my rule `solution_project` only generates me an `SolutionProjectInfo` provider. But I don't understand how I can use this provider to make a call to `cc_binary`, because I can only access values of a provider in a rule, is that right ?

By having something like :

```py
attrs = {
    'project': attr.label(providers = [SolutionProjectInfo])
}
```

## So here is my questions

This questions are independant, I only need one to work

### How could make a call to `cc_binary` in my rule

How could make a call to `cc_binary` in my rule implementation; Aka make a call to `cc_binary` in `_impl_solution_project` of my rule `solution_project`

What I would like to do is a little bit like the presentation of `first-class Macros`/`Symbolic Macros` of future Bazel versions which is not available now.
[Symbolic Macros](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1aOp2TsS6iM0byBxrGMKgnUnBR2ihYr2RGeYuScvduUg/edit#heading=h.5mcn15i0e1ch)

[Symbolic Macros](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/discussions/19921)

```py
def _impl_solution_project(ctx):
    if ctx.attr.project_type == "ConsoleApp":
        native.cc_binary(...)
    elif ctx.attr.project_type == "StaticLib":
        native.cc_library(...)
    ...
    return [SolutionProjectInfo(
        name = ctx.label.name,
        project_type = ctx.attr.project_type,
        defines = ctx.attr.defines,
        include_dirs = ctx.attr.include_dirs,
        srcs = ctx.attr.srcs
    )]
```

Here I get an error of:

```
native.cc_binary can't be called within a rule's implementation
```

### Get values from my provider ouside a rule

How could I get values from my provider outside a rule.

Like doing something like:

```py
solution_project(
    name = "EngineCore",
    type = "StaticLib"
    srcs = glob("/src/**/*.cpp"),
    defines = [ "USE_OPENGL" ],
    include_dirs = [ "EngineCore/src/" ]
    ...
)
```

And then I would have a macro (classic StarLark macro) that make a call to `cc_binary` or `cc_library`

```py
# *.bzl
def solution_project_macro(info_provider):
    if info_provider.project_type == "ConsoleApp":
        native.cc_binary(
            name = info_provider.name
            ...
        )
    elif info_provider.project_type == "StaticLib":
        native.cc_library(...)

# BUILD
solution_project(
    name = "EngineCore",
    type = "StaticLib"
    srcs = glob("/src/**/*.cpp"),
    defines = [ "USE_OPENGL" ],
    include_dirs = [ "EngineCore/src/" ]
    ...
)
solution_project_macro(":EngineCore")
```

## Why

The code shown previously is made up, that is why I don't have any repo using this.

But that is what I am aiming for. The goal is to avoid duplication of defines / dependencies / includes directories when working with multiple static libs. Like, for example I have a graphics engine that needs to have the define USE_OPENGL. I want when building the lib to create a provider that stores that define, among include directories and others so when I set this graphics engine as dependencies I don't have to make a duplication of all these defines and flags in generals. Thanks for any help or if you have any other way to do that.